# WebClient указание кодировки для возвращаемого содежимого веб-страниц

Tags: c#, .net, кодировка

Пытаюсь вернуть с помощью **WebClient** содержимое страниц. Все хорошо, если указана кодировка. Но вот если попытаться отобразить страницу google будут кракозябры.
  Пока есть идея только провести анализ на наличие meta-заголовка, и если его нет, добавить его:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Но он может быть оформлен как угодно, что несколько осложняет его поиск. Намечается вопрос: как можно грамотно указать кодировку выводимой страницы?
Возможно нет необходимости его искать и я упускаю возможности .NET

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  downloadString = client.DownloadString("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно определить при помощи заголовка ответа сервера:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Через HttpWebResponse:

```
const string url = "http://google.com/";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
```

Или через WebClient:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    public string ContentType;

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        if (response != null)
        {
            this.ContentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Получить кодировку по имени можно так:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-32");
```

Начиная с версии .Net 4.5 появилась новая улучшенная [библиотека для HTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).

На nuget.org есть версия [для .Net 4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/).

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите точно определить кодировку - лучше никогда не полагайтесь только на заголовок ответа сервера.

Очень часто кодировка в заголовке ответа и реально используемая кодировка отличаются по различным причинам. А ещё указание кодировки может вообще отсутствовать в заголовке ответа.

`<meta http-equiv="content-type">` - приоритетней HTTP-заголовков, и если он указан, то лучше верить ему. Хотя он тоже не всегда корректен, да и может спокойно отсутствовать.

В идеале нужно выполнить последовательно несколько действий:

1. Посмотреть указанна ли кодировка в HTTP-заголовке Content-Type? Если указанна - запоминаем.
2. Если в начале содержимого есть BOM-байты - прекращаем поиски, и в зависимости от их значений считаем кодировкой содержимого UTF-8, UTF-16, либо UTF-32
3. Произвести парсинг HTML(временно используя в качестве кодировки ASCII), и если есть `meta[http-equiv=content-type]` с указанной в нем кодировкой - заменяем им кодировку найденную на первом шаге
4. Если по результатам 1-3 шагов кодировка не определена - продолжаем парсинг HTML, вытаскиваем из него текстовое содержимое, и определяем его кодировку по результатам его эвристического анализа. Для этого есть готовые проекты `chardetsharp` и `NCharDet`.

Если жестко не задавать WebClient-у кодировку, то он определит её автоматически по 1 и 2 шагу. Найденную кодировку он, к сожалению, никуда не записывает, а только использует её в своих внутренних методах.

Answer (score 0):

Похожий вопрос уже был: [сохранение страницы сайта в читабельном виде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462029/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5)

В моём [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462059/178988) есть код (на VB.NET) определения кодировки страницы по ответу сервера.