# сохранение страницы сайта в читабельном виде

Tags: java, unicode

при сохранении страницы сайта по ссылке с помощью `CloseableHttpClient` в файл получаю   `<meta name="description" content="���������� ������������� ����� ������. ������� ���������` тоесть все что на русском языке превращается в бред.

если загрузить страницу в браузере  которую сохранил то страница превращается в смесь таких бредятин и нормального англ. текста.
            подскажите как исправить кодировку и где лучше это сделать?

```
       StringBuffer resp = new StringBuffer();
        File file = new File("answer2");
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                entity.getContent()))) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                inputLine = String.format("%s%n", inputLine);
                resp.append(inputLine);
            }

            System.out.println(resp.toString());
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),
                            "UTF-8"));) {
                bw.write(resp.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: А в какой кодировке исходная страница?

Comment: @tutankhamun windows-1251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите какая исходная кодировка. Обычно в тексте HTML страницы в одном из первых тегов есть надпись такого вида:

```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Возможно у вас `charset` не `utf-8` а какой-нибудь друго, типа `cp1251`.

Ну а когда опеределите уже можно декодировать указав кодировку 2 параметром в `InputStreamReader()`.

Answer (score 2):

Для записи в файл явно используется кодировка UTF-8. Попробуйте явно задать кодировку и для входного потока, используя конструктор `InputStreamReader` с указанием кодировки:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"))
```

или

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            entity.getContent(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
```

Comment: не помогает.  все равно получается ерунда. может быть проблема в русском тексте или в специальной перекодировке сайта?

Comment: попробовал на нескольких сайтах. на некоторых нормально сохраняет, на некоторых выдает фигню вместо слов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Загружать надо массив байтов, а не строку.
2. Если всё-таки нужна строка, то кодировку страницы можно определить так:

   ```vb
   Public Function DownloadPageContent(ByVal Url As String, Optional ByVal PageEncoding As Encoding = Nothing) As String
     Dim Data() As Byte, EncStr As String, Content As String, EncMatch As Match

     Using WC As New WebClient
       Try
         Data = WC.DownloadData(Url)
         EncStr = WC.ResponseHeaders(HttpResponseHeader.ContentType)
       Catch ex As WebException
         If ex.Response Is Nothing Then Throw
         Using Response As WebResponse = ex.Response
           EncStr = Response.Headers(HttpResponseHeader.ContentType)
           Using Stream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
             Using Reader As New BinaryReader(Stream)
               Data = Reader.ReadBytes(Stream.Length)
             End Using
           End Using
         End Using
       End Try
     End Using

     If PageEncoding IsNot Nothing Then Return PageEncoding.GetChars(Data)

     Content = RemoveHtmlComments(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(Data))
     EncMatch = Regex.Match(Content, "<meta\s+[^>]*?charset\s*=\s*[""']?([-\w]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)

     If EncMatch.Success Then
       EncStr = EncMatch.Groups(1).Value
     ElseIf EncStr IsNot Nothing Then
       EncMatch = Regex.Match(EncStr, "charset\s*=\s*([^,;\s]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
       EncStr = If(EncMatch.Success, EncMatch.Groups(1).Value, Nothing)
     End If

     Return Encoding.GetEncoding(If(EncStr, "UTF-8")).GetChars(Data)
   End Function
   ```

   Подробнее: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6770380#p6770380